# CruiseControl.NET: Displaying generated files as part of the build history

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I have a rake task running on CC.NET that generates HTML test reports. I'd like these test reports to be stored against each build and be accessible from the CC.NET website when looking at the details of the build.

Is there a way of doing this or do you know of another continuous integration server that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

The best I got was moving them into a directory and then making that a virtual directory which can be pointed to by the project's external links. Enable directory browsing and you can click the folder of the last build and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The Java version of CruiseControl has an [artifacts publisher](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#artifactspublisher) for just this kind of thing. I'm pretty sure CC.NET has a similar publisher.